# Extraction of file using numpy memory map python

Tags: python

Trying to extract a sample from of large file using numpy's memmap:

```
# indices - boolean vector indicating which lines we want to extract

file_big = np.memmap('path_big_file',dtype='int16',shape=(indices.shape[0],L))

file_small = np.memmap('new_path_for_small_file',dtype='int16',shape=(indices.sum(),L))
```

The expected result would be that a new file will be created with only part of the data, as identified by the indices.

```
# place data in files:
file_small[:] = file_big[indices]
```

The above is the described procedure in the manual. It does not work - called as not having enough memory, even though memory should not be an issue: using only memmap and not uploading data.

Comment: You can simply index the memap?

Comment: You say "does not work" but don't say *how* - what results are you expecting to get, and what results are actually getting?

Comment: How can I index memmap? there is no such entry in the manual

Comment: You are doing that already in the last line.

Comment: Right - except the last line does not work